# How to target certain text to make bold using css

Tags: html, css

At the moment the CSS selector `.tag` targets all text in the below and makes it bold. How would I just target the "Badge Name" text below

text to make bold?

```
wrapper.append('<div class="tag" >'+ 'Badge Name: '+ item.badgename + '</div>'+ '<br>');
```

Perhaps I need to use a pseudo selector?

Comment: What about searching more?...

Comment: @kougiland I'm still looking after posting the question to try and solve myself, not sure why you feel the need to mark down...

Comment: Dano007 i didn't mark down your question.

Comment: @kougiland ok, sorry!

Comment: @Dano007 Didn't my answer meet your needs?

Comment: @HashemQolami yes it was perfect, just tested it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the "Badge Name: " phrase is constant, one approach is using CSS `:before` pseudo element to generate the content as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/dorib/1/edit)**

```css
.tag:before {
    content: "Badge Name: ";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Hence you could remove that phrase from your script:

```
wrapper.append('<div class="tag" >'+ item.badgename + '</div>'+ '<br>');
```

Another option is wrapping that phrase by an inline wrapper (a `<span>` element) and use `.tag span` selector to apply the proper declarations:

```
wrapper.append('<div class="tag" >'+ '<span>Badge Name:</span> '+ item.badgename + '</div>'+ '<br>');
```

Comment: Just out of interest, using the first option. How would this work if tag is used across multiple wrappers with different titles? at the moment it adds Badge Name: to the start of eevery wrapper using "tag" ?

Comment: @Dano007 It adds "Badge Name: " content to every element which has `.tag` class name. If you want it to be more specific, try adding another class name to the wrapper like: `class="tag badge"` then use the `:before` pseudo element on `.tag.badge` elements. Like so: `.tag.badge:before`

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
wrapper.append('<div class="tag"><span class="badge">Badge Name: </span>'+item.badgename+'</div><br>');
```

Then in your CSS add a style for the badge class that makes it bold.

```
.badge{ font-weight:bold; }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

By modifying your HTML, the CSS could be simplified.
To get this to work, you would be best off wrapping **Badge Name:** in a seperate `<span>`.
As this:

```
<div class='badge'>
  <span class='name'>Badge Name: </span>this is a name
</div>
<br />
```

With styling on `span.name`.

JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/pukoti/3/edit?html,css,output)